# Cannot (programmatically) add song to playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I'm new to JavaScript, so my problem will probably be very easy to fix for someone with any experience. I'm making a music blog with a few friends, and I am trying to make my own custom music player using jPlayer.

I want a simple JavaScript function that you supply the title of the song and the mp3, and it adds itself to the jPlayer playlist. This is the JavaScript function that I have...

```
function add_song(title, mp3)
{
    myPlaylist.add({
        title:"Tempered Song",
        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3"
    });
}
```

I want to be able to call the function anywhere in my body, using this code...

```
<script>
    add_song("Your Face", "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-05-Your_face.mp3");
</script>
```

This, however, doesn't actually add the song. I'm guessing that this has something to do with having to set up the jPlayerPlaylist in the $(document).ready() function. I'm guessing that my variable "myPlaylist" isn't correctly initialized when I try to call add_song(). Like I said, I'm new to JavaScript so try to make it simple for me.

You can check out the code I have at [my website](http://www.startingtofeelit.com/player3/player.php) to better guide me in my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed that you're setting up your `jPlayerPlaylist` *after* you're calling `add_song`. The browsers blocks and runs the Javascript code in `<script>` tags as soon as it encounters them, which is before `document.onload` and jQuery equivalents are fired.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you really want to load up some hardcoded playlist elements right as the page is loading, or do you actually want to attach these to buttons or links? For the former, move the function calls to the onload function, and for the latter, make new event handler functions and attach them to the appropriate elements.

If you're really just going to supply the function manually in the address bar or something, it should work fine. It simply won't work before the page has loaded.

Comment: If you go to the main page, http://www.startingtofeelit.com/, you can get a better idea of what we want to accomplish. Each page has 7 posts on it, which means 7 mp3s per page. I want to dynamically load whichever mp3s are on that current page into the player, so I wanted to create a simple function that will add the mp3 to the player.

I am using Wordpress for the blog, and will be using shortcodes in each post. This shortcode will give the url of the mp3, and I want that shortcode to add it to the playlist. I'm not sure how to do these event handler functions. Could you give me an example?

Comment: One way to do it could be to add each of the new values to an array instead of calling add_song, and then call add_song on each one in your document.ready.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? You're a genius! So one more quick question... That document.ready function is called after the entire page is loaded, correct?

Comment: Yes, if you're referring to `$(document).ready(function(){})`, which you already have in the page you linked to in your original question. You can also simply do `$(function(){})`; it does the same thing.